# Why does the execution stop while using request_html?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests-html

```
session = HTMLSession()
flag = 0
leap_year =[2016,2020]
month_30 = [4,6,9,11]
for year in range(2015,2020):
    date =[]
    times = []
    temp = []
    dew = []
    hum =[]
    wind=[]
    wind_s =[]
    wind_g =[]
    press = []
    precip = []
    cond = []
    for month in range(1,13):
        for day in range(1,32):
            if(year in leap_year):
                if(month == 2 and day >29):
                    break
            else:
                if (month == 2 and day >28):
                    break
            if(month in month_30 and day >30):
                break
            d = "{}-{}-{}".format(year,month,day)
            start2 = time.time()
            url = "https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/ca/richmond/CYVR/date/{}".format(d)

            r = session.get(url)
            r.html.render(sleep =5)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.html.html,'html.parser')
            table = soup.find("tbody",{'role':'rowgroup'})
            row = table.find_all('tr')
            for r in row :
                n = 0
                date.append(d)
                for cell in r.find_all('td'):
                    if(n == 0):
                        times.append(cell.text)
                    elif(n == 1):
                        temp.append(cell.text)
                    elif(n == 2):
                        dew.append(cell.text)
                    elif(n == 3):
                        hum.append(cell.text)
                    elif(n == 4):
                        wind.append(cell.text)
                    elif(n == 5):
                        wind_s.append(cell.text)
                    elif(n == 6):
                        wind_g.append(cell.text)
                    elif(n == 7):
                        press.append(cell.text)
                    elif(n == 8):
                        precip.append(cell.text)
                    elif(n == 9):
                        cond.append(cell.text)
                    n+=1
            end2 = time.time()
            print("it took : {} for one day ".format(end2-start2))
            print(d)

        
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```

Hi! I was trying to scrape the website with request_html. I don't know why during the execution, it suddenly stops. Sometimes, it stops right after fetching the data of 2016-1-20 or sometimes it stops when it is trying to fetch data of 2016-3-20. It randomly stops. Does anyone know why? Are the timeout or sleep in r.html.render the problem?

Answer (score 0):

requests-html module needs a new version of urllib(another module), the version I had was urllib 1.25.7 which until recently was up to date.  Currently urllib 1.25.8 is the newest and is required to use requests-html properly.  To fix this error use:

```
pip3 install urllib3 --upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried it bu it gives : " ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement urllib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for urllib"      on my cmd

Comment: @Lucian sorry for the confusion, it was late when I wrote my answer.  I have updated the command, urllib is a builtin module which can not be modified.  Urllib3 is the correct module.  If you follow my new instructions you should be able to update urllib